# Where to test if the widget is mounted when about to `SetState()`

Tags: flutter, dart, state

Just wanted to make clear where to set the test `if (mounted)` in a stateful widget when about to change a state.

Consider the following code which generates a thumbnail from a video file. The expected result is to set the `_image` state and as it is placed in a future, the `setState()` must be done only if the widget is still mounted.

So the code to right should be:

```dart
  void generateThumbnail() async {
    
    final image = await writeVideoThumbnail(widget.videoPath);
    if (image == null) {
      print("Error generating the image from ${widget.videoPath}");
      return;
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

But, for me, not setting the state makes the whole function useless, so I am tempted to do the following, making the test at the very beginning, hence saving resources:

```dart
  void generateThumbnail() async {
    if (!mounted) return;

    final image = await writeVideoThumbnail(widget.videoPath);
    if (image == null) {
      print("Error generating the image from ${widget.videoPath}");
      return;
    }
    
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }
```

Is it correct? I mean no interrupt could have been fired between the beginning of the function and the `SetState()`?

Comment: Imagine the user clicks a button that calls the `generateThumbnail()` function. That function will await at `writeVideoThumbnail(widget.videoPath);`. Now before future completes, the user clicks the back button on the page, and the widget containing `generateThumbnail()` is removed from the widget tree. The point of `if (!mounted) return;` is to prevent calling `setState` on a widget that is no longer in the tree. The first example code achieves this, the second does not.

Comment: `if (!mounted)` should be called AFTER an async call.